# How to calculate month and member wise total by given year in mysql

Tags: mysql

My two table `members` and `savings` multiple members savings store on savings table on several days, i want to show month wise members saving total on given year name.

`members` table

```
1.id 
2.name
3.account_no
```

`savings` table

```
1.id
2.member_id
3.transaction_date
4.saving_amount
`SELECT
    m.id member_id,
    m.name member_name,
    m.account_no,
    MONTHNAME(s.transaction_date) m,
    MONTH(s.transaction_date) mt,
    ROUND(SUM(s.saving_amount)) total_saving
FROM
    members m,
    savings s
WHERE
    YEAR(s.transaction_date) = 2019 and m.id = s.member_id
GROUP BY
    m
ORDER BY
    mt`
```

> i have tried this sample code but this result is showing only month wise but want to show member and month wise.i want to output that sample image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need full group by clause -

```
SELECT
    m.id member_id,
    m.name member_name,
    m.account_no,
    MONTHNAME(s.transaction_date) m,
    MONTH(s.transaction_date) mt,
    ROUND(SUM(s.saving_amount)) total_saving
FROM
    members m,
    savings s
WHERE
    YEAR(s.transaction_date) = 2019 and m.id = s.member_id
GROUP BY
    m.id member_id,
    m.name member_name,
    m.account_no,
    MONTHNAME(s.transaction_date),
    MONTH(s.transaction_date)
ORDER BY
    mt
```

Comment: Please try now.